# node js LZ4 decodeBlock to decompress loop with Buffer

Tags: node.js, buffer, lz4

Now I am coding for decompress a file, I refer LZ4.decodeBlock in https://github.com/pierrec/node-lz4. But I need read a slice and do decompress with loop. I code as below. It works fine. But it uses a lot of memory. As every slice with new a 64K buffer.

```
decipher.on('readable', ()=> {
      while (1) {
          var body = decipher.read(len);
          if (body) {
            var uncompressed = new Buffer(64*1024);

            var uncompressedSize = lz4.decodeBlock(body, uncompressed);
            var uncompressed_end = uncompressed.slice(0, uncompressedSize);
            outStream.write(uncompressed_end);
          } else {
            break;
          }
        } else {
            break;
        }
       }
      });
  }
```

Then I want to optimize memory usage, I modify it as below. It will use less memory. But It cannot decompress to the same content with original file.

```
var uncompressed = new Buffer(64*1024);
   decipher.on('readable', ()=> {
      while (1) {
          var body = decipher.read(len);
          if (body) {
            var uncompressedSize = lz4.decodeBlock(body, uncompressed);
            var uncompressed_end = uncompressed.slice(0, uncompressedSize);
            outStream.write(uncompressed_end);
          } else {
            break;
          }
        } else {
            break;
        }
       }
      });
  }
```

So how should I optimize memory usage with buffer?

Comment: It's not clear what your expectations are here. You need to load data into memory in order to work with it. Your `uncompress` buffer is only 64k in size, and presumably your `body` buffer is even smaller. The `uncompressed.slice` function doesn't add anything to memory overhead. The LZ4 lib does support a pure streaming mode `input.pipe(encoder).pipe(output)` but presumably it still uses internal buffering.

Comment: Hi Julian, Thanks for your reply. The max length is 64K, so the size is OK. Now my problem is for optimize memory usage. As I use 'new Buffer(64*1024)'  in a loop, so there use a lot of memory. I want to use only one 'new Buffer(64*1024)' to reduce memory usage. But I don't how to use it correctly?

Comment: Your second code sample is more efficient than the first, but that is principally because you reuse the same buffer instance each loop iteration, and so less memory allocation is taking place. But in terms of memory usage, there isn't necessarily much practical difference between the two. This is because memory in JavaScript is garbage collected, and so whilst the first code sample will keep taking memory from heap, it will also keep releasing memory also, as the previous buffer is discarded. Your second code sample is the way to go, and probably about as memory efficient as the code can be.

Comment: I have tested global.gc(), it will use less memory, but it works slowly. I think maybe I can use synchronous decompress slice by slice in loop, then I can reuse only one buffer. As before, in loop, it decompress asynchronously, so I cannot reuse one buffer.

Comment: You shouldn't call the GC directly yourself, let the JS virtual machine manage memory allocations automatically. If you have tight memory restrictions and want more control over heap and GC behaviour then take a look at the v8 options node supports from the command line: https://gist.github.com/listochkin/10973974